# Excel - Replace " / " character within non-formula cells

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, cell, backslash

For example i have two cells

```
A1: =1/2
A2: /abc
```

I want to replace `/` char in second cell with something else without changing first cell which contains formula. Final result should be like this

```
A1: = 1/2
A2: #abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your cells and run:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If Not r.HasFormula Then
            r = Replace(r.Text, "/", "#")
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/a` with `#a` as shown below:

[image: demo]

Comment: thanks this was a solution too but it works only for /a if if I have /b /c ... i have to repeat for all of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula creating a new column: Let's say that the value is in cell A1, you could put this in the cell b1:

```
=IF(ISFORMULA(A1),A1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))
```